# How you you add a fitted quartic regression line on MINITAB?

Tags: regression, regression-analysis

How you you add a fitted quartic regression line on MINITAB?

So for the fitted line plot on the regression section you can select a linear, quadratic and cubic fitted regression plots but there is no option for quartic. Is it at all possible to do it via the non linear regression plot? and how could it be done?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I do not know anything about MiniTab but, assuming you want to fit $$y=a+b x+ cx^2+d x^3+e x^4$$ just define as variables $A_i=x_i$, $B_i=x_i^2$, $C_i=x_i^3$, $D_i=x_i^4$, and your model is just $$y=a+b A+c B+d C+e D$$ and you just need to perform a multi-linear regression.